# Performing a "WHILE" Loop in an Asnyc Function

Tags: powershell, function, while-loop

I definitely feel like I've done my due diligence in trying to sort this one out, so bear with me as I try to explain what I'd like to accomplish.

I have a PowerShell script that automates many different offboarding tasks. Some of these tasks can take quite some time. For example, waiting on an e-mail export to complete can take hours depending on the employee and their length of time with the company. So, rather than performing my "while" loop in the script itself (and log jamming all of the next steps) I am trying to pass it off to an async function to run in the background while the rest of my offboarding script moves along.

I can tell that the async function successfully runs and the required variables are being passed, but... nothing is happening. I'm getting no updates printed to my log file. I'm getting no updates to the entry in my SQL db. I'm truly at a loss with this one.

Here is the call to my function in the main script:

```
$VaultParameters = @{
    employee_name = "$employee_name"
    export_name = "$export_name"
    sql_id = "$sql_id"
    vault_status_id = "$vault_status_id"
}
VaultExport @VaultParameters
```

And here is the function itself:

```
function VaultExport {
    param (
        [cmdletbinding()]
        [parameter()]
        [string]$employee_name,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$export_name,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$sql_id,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$vault_status_id
    )

    $scriptBlock = {
        param ($employee_name,$export_name,$sql_id,$vault_status_id)
        $vault_ready = "no"
        while ($vault_ready -eq "no") {
            $vault_status = gam info export "Email Exports" "$export_name"
            $vault_status = $vault_status -Match "COMPLETED"
            $vault_status = $vault_status -split(": ")
            $vault_status = $vault_status[1]
            Invoke-SqlUpdate -Query "UPDATE ``db_name``.``table_name`` SET ``vault_status`` = '$vault_status' WHERE ``id`` = '$vault_status_id'"
            if ($vault_status -eq "COMPLETED") {
                $vault_ready = "yes"
                $completed = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                Invoke-SqlUpdate -Query "UPDATE ``db_name``.``table_name`` SET ``vault_completed`` = '$completed' WHERE ``id`` = '$vault_status_id'"
                Invoke-SqlUpdate -Query "UPDATE ``db_name``.``table_name`` SET ``vault_status`` = '1' WHERE ``id`` = '$sql_id'"
                $LoggingParameters = @{
                    logfile = "C:\script_logs\threxit.log"
                    log = "INFO: (GVEF, $employee_name) $export_name is ready ($vault_status). Downloading now..."
                }
                EventLogging @LoggingParameters
                Write-Output "$export_name is ready ($vault_status). Downloading now..."
            } else {
                $vault_status = gam info export "Email Exports" "$export_name"
                $vault_status = $vault_status -Match "IN_PROGRESS"
                $vault_status = $vault_status -split(": ")
                $vault_status = $vault_status[1]
                $LoggingParameters = @{
                    logfile = "C:\script_logs\threxit.log"
                    log = "INFO: (GVEF, $employee_name) $export_name is not yet ready ($vault_status). Checking again in ten seconds."
                }
                EventLogging @LoggingParameters
                Write-Output "$export_name is not yet ready ($vault_status). Checking again in ten seconds."
                Start-Sleep 10
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($employee_name,$export_name,$sql_id,$vault_status_id)
}
exit
```

Comment: Can you add some `-verbose` logging? Also is `invoke-sqlupdate` a custom function that you wrote? AFAIK `Invoke-SqlCmd` is used for these type of changes.

Comment: Hey there- Invoke-SqlUpdate is part of the SimplySQL module that I use in my PowerShell scripts. I will try to add some -Verbose to the commands within the scriptBlock. I'm only now learning that Write-Host does not work in a scriptBlock so I'm having a difficult time finding out _what_ is happening once the background job kicks off.

Comment: you can use `write-error` or `write-verbose`

Comment: i also think you need to call the simplySQL module inside the function.

Comment: You can use `Get-Job` and `Receive-Job` to access the output of a background job

Comment: Is the code `VaultExport @VaultParameters` placed somewhere after your declaration of `function VaultExport {`?  The reason I'm asking is that the `exit` placed at the end of the VaultExport function would prevent all code that follows from executing.

Comment: The code `VaultExport @VaultParameters` is in my "main" script.

At the beginning of this script I am calling this function (and others) --- `. ".\function_gam_vault_status.ps1"`.

Yes, I do have an exit at the end of the function. Should I not?

Comment: Additionally, the `Receive-Job` recommendation allowed me to see what happened in that specific background process and it appears that my `Invoke-SqlUpdate` and the call to my event logging function both failed... I am loading the SimplySql module and calling my logging function _within_ the function so I'm not sure. Looking...

Comment: Alright, so I was able to solve the SQL portion by 1) adding the call to the module to the SCRIPTBLOCK and not _just_ the function, and 2) by also authenticating to my SQL server from within the SCRIPTBLOCK itself. Still failing to call the logging function but I'll figure it out.

Comment: I don't think exit at the end of a script is a problem.  But you now have me curious about your function_gam_vault_status.ps1 file.  I've only been deep in PowerShell for around a year now and I thought the only way you could call a external function is if it was in a *.psm1 file.  I think I'm getting what you are doing, and I get why it might work, so now I'm going to go off do some experiments.

Comment: I'm happy to share the most current version of the .ps1 function if that helps you and your experiments!

Comment: `EventLogging` looks like a custom function that may not be available in your job unless you import the module or dot source the script there also.

Comment: EventLogging is a custom function I wrote, yes. At first I thought calling it in the "main" script would be sufficient for the function/background job, but when I learned I had to call my SimplySql model from WITHIN the function itself (and _also_ log into my SQL db from within the function) I added the dot source to EventLogging as well... but that much is still failing.

Comment: I ran my updated function in prod yesterday and the while loop seemed to work just fine, running the gam command every sixty until the export was ready and then properly updated the columns in two separate SQL dbs. However, there is still a weird issue with the logging / my logging function not being called in the scriptBlock.

Almost there!